# How to change port number of apache server in xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin

When we start the appache server in xammp the error occur port no is used how we fix this proboem

Comment: Post the xampp log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ampps and Xampp, from both you may get this warning: *"There is another application running on port 80."*

The solution to this is, you must click on "Configuration" just beside Apache running icon and settings in Ampps. It runs a Notepad.

Search for these two lines `#Listen 12.34.56.78:80` and `Listen 80`. These two lines mean that the port must be on 80, so just change 80 to another port like 8080 and save the changes. Then run the Apache and there should not be problem.